# ng-model not working for certain attributes in angularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

Hi I encountered a problem with ng-model. I want to create an edit page for admin user to edit the rest of the user's permission level. 
So, I listed out all the user's attributes in the edit page, and these attributes should display the current values.

I can update all the attributes correctly, however, the problem is that when visiting the edit page, only certain attributes are displayed while some are not. I think it is the problem with ng-model.

code snippets from my _form.html.erb

```
 <div class="col-md-12 space-1" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form['email'].$invalid }">
  <label class="control-label">Email</label>
   <div class="input-icon right">
    <i ng-show="form['email'].$invalid" class="fa fa-warning tooltips" data-original-title="{{errors['email']}}" data-container="body"></i>
    <input ng-model= "user.email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
 </div>
 <br>

<div class="col-md-12 space-1" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form['events'].$invalid }">
  <label class="control-label">Event Permission Level : {{user.activities.events}}</label>
   <div class="input-icon right">
    <i ng-show="form['events'].$invalid" class="fa fa-warning tooltips" data-original-title="{{errors['events']}}" data-container="body"></i>
    <input ng-model= "user.activities.events" name="activities.events" type="range" max="2" min="0" class="form-control">
 </div>
 </div>
 <br> 

 <div class="col-md-12 space-1" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form['admin_events'].$invalid }">
  <label class="control-label">Admin Event Permission Level : {{user.activities.admin_events}}</label>
   <div class="input-icon right">
    <i ng-show="form['admin_events'].$invalid" class="fa fa-warning tooltips" data-original-title="{{errors['admin_events']}}" data-container="body"></i>
    <input ng-model= "user.activities.admin_events" name="activities.admin_events" type="range" max="2" min="0" class="form-control">
</div>
 </div>
 <br>
```

The code above shows 3 different ng-models, 1.user.email, 2.user.activities.events 3.user.activities.admin_events

The way I process them is the same, but when visiting the edit page, only email and events attributes displayed the current value, but not admin_events. I can update their values alright, but I cannot get admin_events to display its current value when visiting the edit page. This is weird isn't it. I mean if I can see the value of events, why can't I see the value of admin_event since they all belong to the user variable.

Can anyone explain why is it like this? It is very confusing for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please create a fiddle to show which are not working.

Comment: if only `user.activities.admin_events` is not working, it may be related to the `_` notation. Try camel case `user.activities.adminEvents` or `user.activities['admin_events']`.

Comment: it doenst work on fiddle because it needs rails backend also. My project is a hybrid between rails and angularJS. But I can just give the fiddle so that you can see what I have done so far, even though the model won't be there. https://jsfiddle.net/leo277/7ub846kd/2/

Comment: ok, user.activites is a hstore column. So i think it is an array

Comment: @Freezystem, no it is not about the camalcase or the _. When I did what you said, it cant even update correctly anymore. So I don't think the _ is the problem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @koox00, I console.log(response), and the result is :
Object { id: 33, email: "imnew@imnfdfew.com", activities: Object }

Comment: When I console.log($scope.user.activies), this is the output:                                    


Object { organiser: true, admin: false, adminEvents: 2, ticketDistances: 0, ticketCategories: 0, ticketPackages: 0, registrationInfos: 0, userPayments: 0, userParticipants: 1, userLoyalties: 2, 5 more… }

Comment: ok so `admin_events` is actually `adminEvents` ?

Comment: Ok this is weird. I  tried it again and it works. It should be adminEvents. So @Freezystem, you are right. Sorry.

Comment: This is so weird, when i use rails console, i always use admin_events, that is why i keep thinking it should be admin_events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it solved the problem, I quote myself from the comments :

If only `user.activities.admin_events` is not working, it may be related to the `_` notation. Try camel case `user.activities.adminEvents` or `user.activities['admin_events']`.

Comment: it always helps to print out the response in the console like what @koox00 suggested. Thank you guys !!

Comment: underscore is perfectly valid why avoid it? Can you provide any links that suggest that?

Comment: actually, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), @koox00 is right. BTW linters generally advise you to avoid it. Are you sure this solved the problem ?

Comment: the problem was that the attribute was indeed named `adminEvents` and not `admin_events`

Comment: I was thinking of JSHint which advise you to use camelCase variables and dot notation to access object properties. But once again `obj.my_attr` is allowed. @leo277 : my answer seems to be inaccurate, are you sure using camelCase solve the problem ?

Comment: Erm, well .adminEvents works. Probbly it has something to do with conflicts between rails active model and angularjs ng-model. When i use rails console, i get the value of admin_events using the name admin_events. But when i need to retrieve the same admin_events in the angular view, the variable name became adminEvents. I do not remember naming the variable adminEvents, that is why i keep thinking it should be admin_events. Anyway, i print out in the console and the variable name is indeed adminEvents

Comment: That was my guess. I don't know rails very well but I was thinking of a conflict with angular. Maybe rails is forcing camelCase or something like that.